# Runaway argument when using pgfplots to plot from .dat file (solved)

Tags: pgfplots

EDIT: Adding a semicolon to `\addplot table{integralAvgDistM250N.dat}` fixed the "Runaway argument" problem, but now I get a "Missing $ inserted" error instead.

EDIT #2: I forgot to add `$$` to the relevant portion. All is well now.

I'm trying to use pgfplots to create better graphics for my reports, but I can't seem to get it to plot from a .dat file; all I get is a "Runaway argument" error. The file in question has two columns separated by a tab and is comprised of numbers (no headers, no text, nothing).

This is what I have in a test file at the moment:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={M},
ylabel={\langle d_{média} \rangle},
xmin=1, xmax=100,
ymin=0.64, ymax=0.67,
legend pos=north west,
]
\addplot table{integralAvgDistM250N.dat}
\legend{N = 250}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As far as I can tell, every bracket has a pair and every `\begin{}` has an `\end{}`, so the error shouldn't be occurring.
I read the tutorial on Overleaf to write the above, but when it explains how to use data from a file it doesn't give any concrete examples, so it's possible I messed something up. Can anyone help me figure out why this error is occurring?

Comment: Welcome! Does adding a `;` after `\addplot table{integralAvgDistM250N.dat}` help?

Comment: Well, it solves this error and then I get a "Missing $ inserted". I'll update the question.

Comment: Yes, it should be `ylabel={$\langle d_\mathrm{m\'edia} \rangle$},`

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thank you. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: You're welcome! I think as long as your problem is solved it is fine. ;-)